# Grammar behind “你的脑子进水了”。

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

What's the grammar behind the sentence 你的脑子进水了?
Because 你的脑子 here is the object into which 水 the subject entered, right?
Shouldnt it be the other way round then? I am a bit confused.
For example "I entered the room" would be 我进（入）房间了, right?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: cf. ＂外国人实用汉语语法＂，sentence with an S-P (subject-predicate) phrase as the predicate，以主谓词组为谓语的句子，叫主谓谓语句。主谓谓语句的基本格式是：（一）主语---谓语［主谓词组：＂主＂---＂谓＂］他---身体 好。兔子---尾巴 短。这个士兵---胸部受伤了。（二）主语---谓语［主谓词组：＂主＂---＂谓＂（及物(transitive)动词）---＂宾＂（数量词组）］＂汉英词典＂---我有一本。这种上衣---小王做了一件。user：你的脑子进水了 clearly is of  (一）type，better search this site for previous discussion of S-P phrases (some say it is of subject--comment type)

Comment: correction of comment: 2nd last line should have "S-P predicate phrase" (P occurs twice) also instead of "subject-comment" read "topic-comment", also instead of "say it is" read "call it".

Comment: @user6065 you should make that an answer

Comment: the topic must have been covered before，users reluctant to search this site?
看起来相关问题是以前提出而受到充足回答的。不过只是有用户不愿意搜索本网站而已。越来越多的用户已经放弃了写回答，而只是写评论的。原因很简单：回答可以被扣分，可是评论不可以。

Comment: @user6065 If you think it's a duplicate of another question, propose to dedup it. If it's only sort of similar, there's no harm in posting a great answer and getting points for it :)

Comment: @user6065 that's a really odd way to use an SE site. I get that lots of people are afraid of downvotes, but you lose 2 points per downvote, but gain 10 per upvote.

Comment: some users might object that 进水了 is not of type SP but PS instead, however the fact that in relatively few cases the usual order between S and P is reversed seems not to violate the principle defining this type of sentence. Note that ＂实用现代汉语语法＂ when defining 主谓谓语句 talks about 大主语，大谓语，小主语 and 小谓语 w/o arranging the latter 2 in any order: 由主谓短语作谓语的句子叫做主谓谓语句，这是汉语特有的一种句子。为了区别全句的主语、谓语和谓语中的主语、谓语，我们把前者称为大主语、大谓语，后者称为小主语、小谓语。大主语和小主语之间存在一定的关系。主谓谓语句的谓语主要是说明或描写主语的，即主谓谓语句是一种说明或描写的句子。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[进水] is a compound word for [be flooded (v)]

Similar structured terms:

漏水 = [leak (v)] / [leakage (n)]

通电 = [electrify (v)]

充气 = [pump air in (v) / inflate (v)]

> 你的脑子进水了

It means: "Your brain is flooded."   -- 进水 in this sentence is a compound word.

*A flooded brain certainly wouldn't produce solid ideas*

Answer (score 3):

At first sight this seems to be a sentence with S-P predicate of type ＂这个士兵胸部受伤了＂or ＂兔子尾巴短＂with 进水 in unusual order P-S (cf. 来了人，发生事故，etc.). A sentence of undoubtedly S-P as predicate type might be 你的脑子水分含量太大 (our brain water content high, i.e. your brain has high water content), a sentence with usual verb predicate might be 脑袋生锈了 (has become rusty，see web), a sentence with nominal predicate (a noun as predicate might be）脑袋一片空白 (mind goes blank).

On the other hand as stated in the other answer, 进水 is a compound verb, cf. bkrs: 进水 (here) to have water get in (one’s ear, shoes etc), to get flooded;
similarly, 进贼 be burglarized (of a house/etc.), example 我们家进贼了.

Note however the following examples with 进 being combined rather freely with other objects (and  了 between 进 and object, see jukuu):

- 我的鞋里进了沙子. I' ve got some grit / a piece of grit in my shoe.
- 我眼睛里弄进了一粒灰尘。I've got a speck of dust in my eye.
- 他的齿缝里嵌进了一小片食物。He had a morsel of food caught between one tooth and another.

Maybe the last two cases are irrelevant since the verbs now are 弄进，嵌进 i.e.弄,嵌 with complement of result 进.

Another compound using 进, 进货:  stock (a shop) with goods, 这星期没进货.
Also note (bkrs) 左边进人, 右边出人 apparently confirming the exceptional order P-S).

There are examples of both 进水了 and 进了水 e.g. 笔记本电脑进了少量水, same for 进贼  e。g。家里进了贼？

Note that compounds (复合词）are of the following 5 types:

1. 并列 (coordinate; coordinating; juxtaposed),
2. 偏正 (endocentric),
3. 动补 (verb complement),
4. 动宾 (verb-object),
5. 主谓 （subject-predicate).

S in the case of 进水 only 4 or 5 could apply; in case of 4 水 would be object of verb 进, case 5 seems doubtful, since in 主谓 compounds the subject seems to always come first.